# How to set number of columns per page in rml

Tags: odoo, rml

Please, I need to know how to set the number of columns per page in RML which I used to create reports for my Openerp session.
I have tried this but it does not work at all.
so I need your help please who can help me know.

```xml
<condPageBreak height="5cm"/>
```

either this:

```xml
<frame id="first" x1="57.0" y1="57.0" width="481" height="728"/>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.